# Nginx M/Monit password protect

Tags: nginx, port, monit, mmonit

I am trying to protect access to M/Monit web interface:
**Box:**
ubuntu 14.04
nginx 1.8.1
mmonit-3.5.1

I created a mmonit config file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        root /var/www/html;
        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

It does not display the authentication dialog.
I followed [serverfault-Nginx Password Protect Entire Port Number 8081](https://serverfault.com/questions/620735/nginx-password-protect-entire-port-number-8081), but it seems I am getting something done wrong...I am new to nginx.

Anyone has an idea how to go about it?
Should it be in the same `default` server config file?
Cheers

Comment: M/Monit already requires authentication to get to its management and monitoring page. Are you trying to get nginx to do the same thing?

Comment: @ewwhite, you talking about the login page? cause I meant protecting it as you would protect a folder access

Comment: Just place this `server` block in the `default` conf file and got the following error: `bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)'

Comment: `$netstat -tulpn = tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6303/mmonit `

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out...
(This is under default server config)

```
root /var/www/html/;
server_name localhost;

location /mmonit/ {
    proxy_pass http://yourServerIp:8080/;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/your/password/file/;
    index index.csp;
}
```

`ln -s /path/to/your/mmonit/folder/ /var/www/html/`
Gives:
`mmonit -> /path/to/your/mmonit/folder/`

Now point you browser at: `http://yourServerIp/mmonit/`
And you will have the 'Authentication Required' dialog box!
`A username and password are being requested by http://yourServerIp. The site says: "Restricted Content"`

**I do suggest calling the link something else then mmonit....to you choice.
Any wayz your access is now double protected!